# Кластеризация меток яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Помогите решить проблему кластеризации меток. Есть карта на ней отображаются метки с разными цветами (зеленые, красные, оранжевые). При клике на метку выводиться балун с названием метки и описание, подсказка показывается при наведении на метку.
Так как метки будут близко друг к другу нужно кластеризовать, но сохранив функционал отображения информации как описал выше.

Вот содержимое JS карт

```
var myMap, myCollection;

    ymaps.ready(init);

  function init () {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.753237, 37.618687],
        zoom: 10.31
        }, {
            balloonMaxWidth: 300
            });

    myMap.controls
        .add('zoomControl');
        myMap.controls.add('typeSelector')  ;
    var MyBalloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<strong>$[properties.name]</strong>' +
    '<p>$[properties.description]</p>'
    );

    $.getJSON("vivodpointsmap.php",
function(json){
for (i = 0; i < json.markers.length; i++) {

var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([json.markers[i].lat,json.markers[i].lon], {
            name: json.markers[i].icontext,
            description: json.markers[i].balloontext,
            hintContent: json.markers[i].hinttext
            },{
                balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayoutClass,
                preset: json.markers[i].styleplacemark
            });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
}


});

    $('#image').change(function(){
        $('.add-on').find('img:first').attr('src', $('#image option:selected').attr('data-path'));
    });

    $('#addmarker').click( function () {

    var name = $('#marker_name').val();

    var hintText = $('#marker_hint').val();

    var address = $('#marker_address').val();
    var adlat = $('#marker_lat').val();
    var adlon = $('#marker_lon').val();

    var balloonText = $('#marker_balloontext').val();

    var stylePlacemark = $("#image option:selected").val();



    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode([adlat,adlon]);
    myGeocoder.then(
        function (res) {
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
            marker = new ymaps.Placemark(coords,
            {
            name: name,
            description: balloonText,
            hintContent: hintText
            },{
                balloonContentLayout: MyBalloonContentLayoutClass,
                preset: stylePlacemark
            });

            $("#res").load("addmetki.php", {icontext: name, hinttext : hintText, balloontext : balloonText, styleplacemark : stylePlacemark, lat : firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()[0], lon : firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()[1]});


            myMap.geoObjects.add(marker);
        },
        function (err) {
            alert('Ошибка');
        }
    );


    });

    }
```

файл vivodpointsmap.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require ("bd.php");

if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mapmetki");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while ($mar = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$json =  array(icontext=>$mar['iconText'], hinttext=>$mar['hintText'], balloontext=>$mar['balloonText'], styleplacemark=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], lat=>$mar['lat'], lon=>$mar['lon']);
$markers[] = $json;
}

}
$points = array(markers=>$markers);

echo json_encode($points);

}


?>
```

Comment: нашел пример что касается разного цвета меток http://yandex.github.io/ymaps-pie-chart-clusterer/
тут кусок кода
https://github.com/yandex/ymaps-pie-chart-clusterer

как мне подгрузить свои данные из таблицы бд и подставить под точки 

var points = [
            new ymaps.Placemark(....

Comment: Посмотрите примеры в песочнице Яндекса, там много вариантов и как загрузить свои данные и как отобразить: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_pie_chart